# Is there a repository for source separation test images e.g. the star-galaxy images?

Tags: image-processing, reference-request, source-separation, data-request

I'm having trouble finding standard images used for testing source-separation algorithms in image processing. For instance, a common example I see is the "star-galaxy" images. Most papers I've seen cite the following paper as their source of the image:

> M. B. McCoy, V. Cevher, Q. T. Dinh, A. Asaei, and L. Baldassarre,Convexity in source separation:  Models, geometry, and algorithms, IEEE Signal Processing Magazine, 31 (2014), pp. 87–95.

However, upon looking at that article, it says their image is from NASA/JPL-Caltech and used with their permission. I haven't been able to find a download link anywhere. Any references in the right direction would be very helpful!

Comment: https://www.nasa.gov/ main menu **Galleries** submenu **Image Galleries**; as of Jan 12, on the page https://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/imagegallery/index.html, browse to the last, bottom right image **Space Images from NASA's Jet Propulsion Laboratory**, click it, on the https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/images/ check a topic 'Stars and Galaxies' to apply the filter and get (as of Jan 12) 19 results

Comment: @V.V.T Thank you for the help, but these galleries apparently do not contain the source separation images from the article in my question. (a free version of them, is viewable on p. 14 of this manuscript https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.10508.pdf )